# Read settings from the configuration file of other application

Tags: c#, configuration-files

The application needs to use the settings from the configuration file of another application on the same machine. Can I use the classes from the System.Configuration namespace or I should parse it as xml-file?

Answer (score 1):

You can read any configuration file using the [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) API.

There is a complete working example in the linked documentation.

Comment: When I try using OpenExeConfiguration or OpenMappedExeConfiguration and get the section from a custom section group, I have got error "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for Crawlers/Configuration: Could not load file or assembly 'Crawler.Core' or one of its dependencies."
What can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This try:

```
ConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new  
ConfigurationFileMap(<filename>);
Configuration managerConfiguration =   
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
```

Comment: When I try using OpenExeConfiguration or OpenMappedExeConfiguration and get the section from a custom section group, I have got error "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for Crawlers/Configuration: Could not load file or assembly 'Crawler.Core' or one of its dependencies." What can I do in this situation?